# TomEE 7.0.2 how to disable CXF + RS

Tags: java, cxf, resteasy, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I would like to use RESTEasy with my webapp deployed to TomEE.
How do I disable CXF so it will not try to start REST services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set `disabled=true` in `conf/conf.d/cxf-rs.properties` (start once to let tomee create the file or create it yourself, it is not there by default)

Comment: Can this done per war basis?